# Jquery toggle on 3 divs

Tags: jquery, toggle

HTML:

```
<div id="bottomContent" class="bottom_content" > <p>First Content</p> </div>

<div id="bottomContent2" class="bottom_content" > <p>second Content</p> </div>

<div id="bottomContent3" class="bottom_content" > <p>Third Content</p> </div>
```

JS:

```
   $("div.one").click (function(){
      $("#bottomContent2").hide();
      $("#bottomContent3").hide();
      $("#bottomContent").animate({width: "toggle"}, 1000);
    });

    $("div.two").click (function(){
       $("#bottomContent").hide();
       $("#bottomContent1").hide();
       $("#bottomContent2").animate({width: "toggle"}, 1000);
    });

    $("div.three").click (function(){
       $("#bottomContent").hide();
       $("#bottomContent2").hide();
       $("#bottomContent3").animate({width: "toggle"}, 1000);
    });
```

I have the following jQuery code whereby when each of the divs is clicked, it will animate its own corresponding div item and close any other div that may be already opened but I am sure there are better ways to code it and make it more compact than I have done. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can we have some html markup to show the layout?

Comment: @mgraph: <div id="bottomContent" class="bottom_content" >
<p>First Content</p>
</div>

<div id="bottomContent2" class="bottom_content" >
<p>second Content</p>
</div>

<div id="bottomContent3" class="bottom_content" >

<p>Third Content</p>
</div>

Comment: Sorry, missed out the top divs. Here they are: <div class="scriptHolder"> <div class="one"></div> <div class="two"><img src="images/question-mark-3d_off.png" width="300" height="210" alt="question" class="rollover" /> </div> <div class="three"></div> </div><!--End scriptHolder--> <div id="bottomContent" class="bottom_content" > <p>First Content</p> </div> <div id="bottomContent2" class="bottom_content" > <p>second Content</p> </div> <div id="bottomContent3" class="bottom_content" > <p>Third Content</p> </div></div>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always approach this problem by putting some extra metadata (using `data-*` attributes) on the element being clicked to associated it's content:

```
<div class="action" data-content="#bottomContent">
  Click me for bottom content
</div>
<div class="action" data-content="#bottomContent1">
  Click me for bottom content 1
</div>
<div class="action" data-content="#bottomContent2">
  Click me for bottom content 2
</div>
```

Notice ive also given all three div's the same class, enabling me to associate the same action with all three.

Then the jQuery becomes:

```
$("div.action").click (function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    $('div.action').not($this).each(function(){
       var $other = $(this);
       var otherTarget = $other.data('content');
       $(otherTarget).hide();       
    });

    var target = $this.data('content');        
    $(target).animate({width: "toggle"}, 1000);

});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/rHKML/

Comment: Thanks Jamiec but from the above example, u're only using 3 divs. In my example, I have the 1st three divs to click interchangeably and another three below to display dependent on which one was clicked at the top: See html above

Comment: @olootu Yes he has only put in 3 Divs but this will function for what you wish and it is scalable for the number of items you wish to toggle.

Comment: @olootu - Yes, but see my live example on jsfiddle, as it has the 3 content div's too. Just wasnt directly relevant to the answer.